# The playback of netflix videos freezes from time to time using Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04, video, netflix

I have issues with playing videos since I upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.

I have tested it with different kernels:

- 5.15.0-* kernels: no issue and the processor usage is much lower.
- 5.17.0-1034-oem: it stops during the boot.
- 5.19.0-50: it starts, but it doesn't recognize the sound card, 2nd monitor.
- 6.1.0-1025-oem: it plays Youtube videos properly but stops from time to time playing Netflix. There is pike in the processor usage. It doesn't seem to affect other apps. It comes every 25 seconds. Regardless I run any app or not.
- 6.2.0-36: the voice doesn't stop, only the videos. It affects every application. If I type a text in Gedit then the characters appear a few seconds later from time to time. I have checked the system monitor. There is a pike in multiple CPU cores (average 2-4 of 16) every time when it happens. First I thought it is caused by the Firefox's "Isolated Web Co". But the situation is the same if I quit Firefox. Actually if I quit every app and disconnect every Bluetooth device then the issues is still there. It happens every 25 seconds: high CPU usage for 1-2 seconds.

I use Dell G15 5510 notebook:

- 16 GB memory
- Intel® Core™ i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 16
- NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] / NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2

Any idea what should I do to fix this issue with the 6.x kernels?